# Transform an SQL statement to Eloquent query builder

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have an SQL query that I find hard to translate it to a Laravel Eloquent query. I tried it with workbench and it works fine.

```sql
SELECT fi.id,fi.internal_name,fi.nombre_contacto,fi.apellidos_contacto,fi.category,
COALESCE(SUM(fi.totalClicks), 0) AS totalclicks FROM(

   SELECT af.id,af.internal_name,af.nombre_contacto,
            af.apellidos_contacto,af.category,SUM(afc.clicks) AS totalClicks
   FROM afiliados_referral_clicks afc, afiliados af WHERE  afc.idAfiliado = af.id
    and fecha >= DATE('2021-07-01') AND fecha<= DATE('2021-07-31')
   GROUP BY af.id 
UNION
SELECT af.id,af.internal_name,af.nombre_contacto,
        af.apellidos_contacto,af.category, 0 AS totalClicks 
FROM afiliados af   ) as fi
GROUP BY fi.id
LIMIT 7000
;
```

What did I try? I can see there are 3 SELECTs in the query, the outer one (parent).

```sql
SELECT fi.id,fi.internal_name,fi.nombre_contacto,fi.apellidos_contacto,fi.category,COALESCE(SUM(fi.totalClicks), 0) AS totalclicks 
FROM(somewhere as fi)
```

And two inner ones (child1).

```sql
SELECT af.id,af.internal_name,af.nombre_contacto,
            af.apellidos_contacto,af.category,SUM(afc.clicks) AS totalClicks
 FROM afiliados_referral_clicks afc, afiliados af WHERE  afc.idAfiliado = af.id
    and fecha >= DATE('2021-07-01') AND fecha<= DATE('2021-07-31')
 GROUP BY af.id 
UNION
something
```

**child2**

```sql
something
UNION
SELECT af.id,af.internal_name,af.nombre_contacto,
        af.apellidos_contacto,af.category,0 AS totalClicks
```

My approach was to make 3 separate queries and merge them.

**child1**

```php
$child1 = $db->table($db::raw('afiliados, afiliados_referral_clicks'))
            ->whereColumn('afiliados.id','=','afiliados_referral_clicks.idAfiliado')
            ->addSelect(['afiliados.id','internal_name','nombre_contacto','apellidos_contacto'])
            ->selectRaw("COALESCE(SUM(clicks), 0) AS totalClicks")
            ->whereBetween('afiliados_referral_clicks.fecha',[$params['fechaReservaFrom'],$params['fechaReservaTo']])
            ->groupBy('afiliados.id')
            ;
```

**child2**

```php
$child2 = $db->table('afiliados')
            ->addSelect(['id','internal_name','nombre_contacto','apellidos_contacto'])
            ->selectRaw("0 AS totalClicks")
            ;
```

The parent will unite both children.

```php
$parent = $child1->union($child2)
        ->addSelect(['afiliados.id','afiliados.internal_name','afiliados.nombre_contacto','afiliados.apellidos_contacto'])
        ->selectRaw("COALESCE(SUM(totalClicks), 0) AS totalClicks")
        ->get()
        ;
```

But when executing the code I get this error.

> 400 (SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'totalClicks' in 'field list'

I think I'm on the right track though, if I return $child1->get() or $child2->get() I get the collections just fine, the issue I believe is in the $parent since I don't know how to access the totalClicks column I added in $child2.

Of course, that's what I tried, I could still have something horribly wrong, I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: What have you tried ? did you encounter errors/difficulties in your tries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right approach separating the queries into 3 different ones.
This should be the same query you posted.

```php
$union = DB::query()
  ->select(
    'af.id',
    'af.internal_name',
    'af.nombre_contacto',
    'af.apellidos_contacto',
    'af.category'
  )
  ->selectRaw('0 as totalClicks')
  ->from('afiliados', 'af');

$sub = DB::query()
  ->select(
    'af.id',
    'af.internal_name',
    'af.nombre_contacto',
    'af.apellidos_contacto',
    'af.category'
  )
  ->selectRaw('sum(afc.clicks) as totalClicks')
  ->from(DB::raw('afiliados_referral_clicks afc, afiliados af'))
  ->whereColumn('afc.idAfiliado', 'af.id')
  ->where('fecha', '>=', DB::raw('date(\'2021-07-01\')'))
  ->where('fecha', '<=', DB::raw('date(\'2021-07-31\')'))
  ->groupBy('af.id')
  ->union($union);

$query = DB::query()
  ->select(
    'fi.id',
    'fi.internal_name',
    'fi.nombre_contacto',
    'fi.apellidos_contacto',
    'fi.category'
  )
  ->selectRaw('coalesce(sum(fi.totalClicks), 0) as totalclicks')
  ->from($sub, 'fi')
  ->groupBy('fi.id')
  ->limit(7000);

dd($query->toSql());

$results = $query->get();
```